# How to retrieve a particular property from array of objects based on multiple conditions using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects like below,

```
const arr_obj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        jobs: [
            {
                completed: false,
                id: '11',
                run: {
                    id: '6',
                    type: 'type1',
                },
            },
            {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '14',
                 run: {
                     id: '17',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },

             },
             {
                 completed: false,
                 id: '12',
                 run: {
                     id: '7',
                     type: 'type2',
                 },
             },
         ],
     },
     {
         id: '2',
         jobs: [
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '13',
                 run: {
                     id: '8',
                     type: 'type2',
                 },
             },
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '16',
                 run: {
                     id: '9',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },

             }, 
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '61',
                 run: {
                     id: '19',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },
             },
         ],
     },
     {
         id: '3',
         jobs: [
             {
                 completed: false,
                 id: '111',
                 run: {
                     id: '62',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },
             },
         ],
     },
 ],
```

and  an arr_ids = ["1","2"]

now i have to filter those ids from arr_obj matchings arr_ids which i do like so

```
const filteredIds = arr_obj.filter(obj => arr_ids.includes(obj.id));


so the filtered_arrobj = [
     {
         id: '1',
         jobs: [
             {
                 completed: false,
                 id: '11',
                 run: {
                     id: '6',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },
             },
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '14',
                 run: {
                     id: '17',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },

             },
             {
                 completed: false,
                 id: '12',
                 run: {
                     id: '7',
                     type: 'type2',
                 },
             },
         ],
     },
     {
         id: '2',
         jobs: [
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '13',
                 run: {
                     id: '8',
                     type: 'type2',
                 },
             },
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '16',
                 run: {
                     id: '9',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },

             }, 
             {
                 completed: true,
                 id: '61',
                 run: {
                     id: '19',
                     type: 'type1',
                 },
             },
         ],
     },  
     ]
```

Now i will have to get the ids from filtered_arrobj whose runs are of type "type1" and none of the jobs have completed: false.

so the expected output from filtered_arrobj is "2"

here in the above example id "1" is not taken because id "1" has job completed: true but it also has job completed: false for type "type1".

**what i have tried?**

```
const output = filtered_arrobj.map(obj => obj.jobs.map(job => job.run.type === 
"type1" && job.completed === true));
        


when i log the output its gives like so

[ 
    [false,true,false],
    [true,true,true]
]
```

this not giving me the id of the obj whose job has run of type = "type1" and which has no jobs completed: false.

how can i get that. could someone help me with this. I am new to programming and learning on the go. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` on arrObj filtered by `arrIds` which you already did, after that filter for `jobs` array (inside above filter) which contains type as `type1` and then check if `filtered jobs` has completed as true then return true otherwise false.

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    id: '1',
    jobs: [
      {
        completed: false,
        id: '11',
        run: {
          id: '6',
          type: 'type1',
        },
      },
      {
        completed: true,
        id: '14',
        run: {
          id: '17',
          type: 'type1',
        },

      },
      {
        completed: false,
        id: '12',
        run: {
          id: '7',
          type: 'type2',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    jobs: [
      {
        completed: true,
        id: '13',
        run: {
          id: '8',
          type: 'type2',
        },
      },
      {
        completed: true,
        id: '16',
        run: {
          id: '9',
          type: 'type1',
        },

      },
      {
        completed: true,
        id: '61',
        run: {
          id: '19',
          type: 'type1',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    jobs: [
      {
        completed: false,
        id: '111',
        run: {
          id: '62',
          type: 'type1',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const arrIds = ["1", "2"];

const filteredIds = arrObj.filter(obj => {
  if (arrIds.includes(obj.id)) {
    const jobs = obj.jobs.filter(job => job.run.type === "type1");
    if (jobs.length > 0) {
      return jobs.every(job => job.completed === true);
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(filteredIds);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. this works perfectly fine to the question. but this code misses one extra thing. the filteredIds should also include object if the job run has no type with 'type1'. so this object should also be added to filteredIds. how can it be done.

Comment: You didn't mention that condition in your question. If you need to include object which has type value other than `type1`, then also need to add that condition to include those objects. Can you give the example input and expected output?

Comment: i have found a solution to the extended question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This example iterates over the data array with a simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop and uses [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the required conditions.

```js
const data=[{id:"1",jobs:[{completed:false,id:"11",run:{id:"6",type:"type1"}},{completed:true,id:"14",run:{id:"17",type:"type1"}},{completed:false,id:"12",run:{id:"7",type:"type2"}}]},{id:"2",jobs:[{completed:true,id:"13",run:{id:"8",type:"type2"}},{completed:true,id:"16",run:{id:"9",type:"type1"}},{completed:true,id:"61",run:{id:"19",type:"type1"}}]}];

let out = [];

for (let obj of data) {

  // Find out if the jobs of type1 have all completed...
  const runCompleted = obj.jobs.every(job => {
    return job.completed && job.run.type === 'type1';
  });

  // If not add the id to the output array
  if (!runCompleted) out.push(obj.id);
}

// And then you just check the length of the array
console.log(out);
console.log(out.length);
```

Comment: thanks but what is completed: !0 and completed: !1 if completed!0 is true then i would expect the output to be "2"

Comment: Sorry @stackuser. 1) I misunderstood the question and 2) my minifier did something terrible with your data. I hope this update will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in one iteration, something like this:

```
const output = arr_obj.filter(obj => {
    let hasType1 = false;
    return (
        arr_ids.includes(obj.id) &&
        obj.jobs.every(job => {
            if (job.run.type === 'type1') hasType1 = true;
            return job.completed === true;
        }) &&
        hasType1
    );
});
```

Or if you only need to check for completeness on `type1` jobs:

```
const output = arr_obj.filter(obj => {
    let hasType1 = false;
    return (
        arr_ids.includes(obj.id) &&
        obj.jobs.every(job => {
            if (job.run.type === 'type1') {
                hasType1 = true;
                return job.completed === true;
            }
            return true;
        }) &&
        hasType1
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

````
const arr = arr_obj.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    const doSatisfyCondition = arr_ids.includes(current.id) && current.jobs.every(item => item.completed) && current.jobs.some(item => item.run.type === "type1")
    if (doSatisfyCondition) accumulator.push(current.id);
    return accumulator;

}, [])
console.log(arr)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job?

```
const ids = new Set(arr_ids);
const filtered_objects = arr_obj.filter(el => ids.has(el.id));
```

The Set constructor creates a Set of Ids insread of an array. This enables you to use the has-function to check if the id property of the element coming from the arr_obj array is in the set "ids".

If you are new to programming you could check in to the Set and Map data structure and its related functions. There are some really good ways to filter and merge data if you can create some kind of uniqueness for every element in the array that you want to create a set from. In this example the Id is a good unique value.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves the problem, it is a bit focused on optimization but it works.

```js
const arr=[{id:"1",jobs:[{completed:!1,id:"11",run:{id:"6",type:"type1"}},{completed:!0,id:"14",run:{id:"17",type:"type1"}},{completed:!1,id:"12",run:{id:"7",type:"type2"}}]},{id:"2",jobs:[{completed:!0,id:"13",run:{id:"8",type:"type2"}},{completed:!0,id:"16",run:{id:"9",type:"type1"}},{completed:!0,id:"61",run:{id:"19",type:"type1"}}]},{id:"3",jobs:[{completed:!1,id:"111",run:{id:"62",type:"type1"}}]}];
 
// For optimitation
const targets = ["1", "2"].reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c]: true}), {})

const result = arr.filter(data => {
  if(targets[data.id]) {
    let containType1 = false
    const jobs = data.jobs
    
    const canSave = jobs.every(job => {
      const isType1 = job.run.type === "type1"
      containType1 = isType1 ? true : containType1
      return isType1 ? job.completed : true
    })
    
    return canSave && containType1
  }
  
  return false
})
 
console.log(result)
```